# How can I get items from current page in PagedCollectionView?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, mvvm, datagrid

I've got my objects in [PagedCollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.pagedcollectionview%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) bound to DataGrid and DataPager.

```
var pcView = new PagedCollectionView(ObservableCollection<Message>(messages));
```

How can I easily get items from current page in PagedCollectionView from my ViewModel? I wish there were something like this:

```
var messagesFromCurrentPage = pcView.CurrentPageItems; // error: no such a property
```

There are properties like SourceCollection, PageIndex and Count but I don't find them useful in this case. What am I missing here?

Comment: If you bind your DataGrid and DataPager to the PagedCollectionView then the items should show up in the dg. Is this not working?

Comment: @Bryant Everything shows up correctly. I just want to programmatically get ("select") items from my ViewModel, where I have access to my pagedCollectionView but no access to the DataGrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get select items you can just use Linq to do it.

```
var items = pcView.Where(i => i.SomeCondition == true);
```

Make sure you add a using statement for System.Linq.

**Edit**: Whenever I have a question as to what is really going on I just look at the code using Reflector (or ILSpy). In this case here is the relevant code inside GetEnumerator() which is how the Select or Where gets the items in the list:

```
    List<object> list = new List<object>();
    if (this.PageIndex < 0)
    {
        return list.GetEnumerator();
    }
    for (int i = this._pageSize * this.PageIndex; i < Math.Min(this._pageSize * (this.PageIndex + 1), this.InternalList.Count); i++)
    {
        list.Add(this.InternalList[i]);
    }
    return new NewItemAwareEnumerator(this, list.GetEnumerator(), this.CurrentAddItem);
```

So you can see how it is returning only the items in the current page from this code.

Comment: But what condition should I use to select only those items that are visible on the current page? PagedCollectionView has a property PageIndex that points to the current page, but no propety with "current items".

Comment: It should only return the current items.

Comment: Wow, I have totally missed that. GetEnumerator() lets you iterate through items in view after paging, so it is exactly what I was looking for. Code documentation wasn't really helpful here... Thanks!